# okhttp java.lang.Illegal ArgumentException: unexpected url

Tags: java, okhttp

I used okhttp to interact with microservices, and last night I got such an error as `java.lang.Illegal ArgumentException: unexpected url: http://dd.zydtrip.net:7080/api/device/bike/heartbeat`

The exception was thrown 30 minutes after the normal operation of the service. This URL should be normal. The exception can not be reproduced at present. Why throwing this exception? The version I use is 3.3.1

`return new Request.Builder().url(url)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", contentType)
                .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("charset=utf-8"), reqMsg.encode()))
                .build();`

The error is:

```
23:18:36,105 ERROR BikeMessageReceiver:41 - unexpected url: http://dd.zydtrip.net:7080/api/device/bike/heartbeat
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected url: http://dd.zydtrip.net:7080/api/device/bike/heartbeat
        at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:141)
        at com.ziytek.bike.access.utils.ServiceInteract.getRequest(ServiceInteract.java:76)
        at com.ziytek.bike.access.utils.ServiceInteract.sendMessage(ServiceInteract.java:106)
        at com.ziytek.bike.access.service.DeviceService.sendHeartBeat(DeviceService.java:98)
        at com.ziytek.bike.access.impl.BikeMessage300Receiver.handleMessageSpecific(BikeMessage300Receiver.java:58)
        at com.ziytek.bike.access.BikeMessageReceiver.handleMessage(BikeMessageReceiver.java:28)
        at com.ziytek.message.exchange.impl.AbstractUMForwarder.handleRequestMessage(AbstractUMForwarder.java:140)
        at com.ziytek.message.exchange.impl.AbstractUMForwarder.forwardMessage(AbstractUMForwarder.java:53)
        at com.ziytek.message.exchange.impl.AbstractUMForwarder$MessageTask.run(AbstractUMForwarder.java:97)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to troubleshoot your issue if you're using an older version (3.3.1) as the latest is now 3.12.1 and source code for `Request.java` has significantly changed then.

In its current iteration, that class no longer throws an `unexpected url` error message anymore.

Source code:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Request.java#L141

Anyways, I did a URL validation for you on `http://dd.zydtrip.net:7080/api/device/bike/heartbeat` and it seems to be valid. This was done using the `org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator` class.

My suggestion would be for you to ensure that you are using the latest library, and then rerun see what the results are. It would make debugging easier.